# Powershell get-host privatedata , how does it work?

Tags: powershell, colors, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am still learning and learning and when I scrolled through the powershell tips of the weeks on the official technet microsoft page.
I stopped here :

[Modifying Message Colors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692799.aspx)

And I tried that out to modify for example my warning backgroundcolor.
When I now use `Write-Warning "This is a warning Message"` the color changed and everything worked as expected.

But where the hell is this info stored ? this privatedata, can I access the file somehow? 
Can anyone give me more information about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The psobject `PrivateData` is a property of the PSHost object, it is not stored in a file.  Observe:

```
PS C:\> $a = Get-Host

PS C:\> $a.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
False    False    InternalHost                             System.Management.Automation.Host.PSHost

PS C:\> $a | Get-Member -Name PrivateData

    TypeName: System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHost

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
PrivateData Property   psobject PrivateData {get;}
```

From the TechNet link you've provided:

> About the only thing you need to keep in mind here is that these changes are not permanent: the colors will revert to their default values when you exit and then restart PowerShell. But that’s no big deal: if you’re dead set on using custom colors for these special message types then simply add your color-changing code to your Windows PowerShell profile.

Comment: @RayofCommand The variable `$PROFILE` will show where your PowerShell profile is located.  e.g. `C:\Users\jscott\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

Comment: There are multiple profiles - use $profile | format-list -force to see them all.